# How can I use a common base path to import from with a generic less webpack setup?

Tags: webpack, less, less-loader

I am using a web stack of typescript+react and less together with webpack.

My webpack ruleset for less files looks like the following:

```
rules: [
{
    test: /\.less/,
    use: [
        "style-loader",
        "css-loader",
        "less-loader",
    ],
},
```

I do have a bit of difficulties figuring out how to do some proper less importing now.

I created a file containing some common definitions, called "Colors.less". It resides in `React/Common/Styles/Colors.less`.

It's content for now:

```
@navy: #001f3f;
```

Now, I want to import this file from another file residing here: `React/Modules/Chat/Styles/ChatWidgetTopBar.less`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
@import (reference) "../../../../Common/Styles/Colors.less";

.ChatWidgetTopBar {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: @navy;

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This also works just fine, however, is there also a possibility to set a common base path for less imports? So that I wouldn't have to do this relative ../../ etc.? I read that webpack allows you to combine variables e.g. `@basepath = "mybasepath/folder"` into something like `@import "{basePath}/folder2`, but how can I make that `@basepath` shared then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules),
Something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: ['<youbasepath>']
    },
    ...
}
```

This way webpack will try to resolve your .less module from this path root.